# on duplicate key update in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, on-duplicate-key

How can I use `insert` statement with `on duplicate key update` like MySQL in Snowflake?

MySQL code :

```
INSERT INTO table (column_list)
VALUES (value_list)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
   c1 = v1, 
   c2 = v2,
   ...;
```

Since snowflake does not support `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, how can I implement the same in snowflake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the MERGE command

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/merge.html